# Order an embedded Form in Symfony 1.4

Tags: php, mysql, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I'm trying to order an embedded form in an SF1.4 backend module by one of the values.

$this->embedRelation('MyInnerForm as innerForm');

gives me a Table that shows Edit-Forms for all entries in MyInnerForm. I want it to be ordered the right way. Can't find a way to modify the query to add an orderBy-Option or (would be better) to sort the result-array using PHP. Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to order?

Comment: I got an embededRelation which shows entrys from a foreign table in a modules edit-mode. I want to order the rows by one of the fields. Like ordering phone numbers by country-code (or anything) in this example: http://di-side.com/di-side/symfony-embedrelation-one-to-many-doctrine-relations/

For now I solved this by buffering $set['InnerFormFields']->render() in an array, which I sort using usort() in the _form template. I think, that's not best practice.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the code of `embedRelation`: it simply get your association, run a foreach on it and call `embedForm`.

```
  $subForm = new sfForm();
  foreach ($this->getObject()->$relationName as $index => $childObject)
  {
    $form = $r->newInstanceArgs(array_merge(array($childObject), $formArgs));

    $subForm->embedForm($index, $form, $innerDecorator);
    $subForm->getWidgetSchema()->setLabel($index, (string) $childObject);
  }

  $this->embedForm($fieldName, $subForm, $decorator);
```

See the `$this->getObject()->$relationName` part? There is no option to order the embed forms, but you can embed them yourself.

```
<?php
  foreach ($this->getObject()->getMyInnerFormOrderedByStuff() as $index => $childObject)
  {
    $form = new InnerFormForm($childObject); // todo!!

    $subForm->embedForm($index, $form, $innerDecorator);
    $subForm->getWidgetSchema()->setLabel($index, (string) $childObject);
  }

  $this->embedForm($fieldName, $subForm, $decorator);
```

You have to implement `getMyInnerFormOrderedByStuff()` and that's it.

Comment: @mene Or if you have to use the same order everywhere you can add an [`orderBy: column_name`](http://www.testically.org/2010/09/30/did-you-know-that-you-can-sort-your-doctrine-relations-by-setting-an-orderby-option-in-your-schema/) to the relation definition and then the relation will be order by that column every time when it accessed lazily.

Comment: To the relation def in schema.yml? That would be awesome!

Comment: Yes you can do what @1ed tell, it will works the same as calling a custom `getMyInnerFormOrderedByStuff` method!